# Как остановить самописный сайт на тех работы?

Tags: безопасность

Допустим произошла внештатная ситуация, недоброжелатель решил навредить моему сайту.

Как можно остановить работу сайта (Скриптов, модулей и пр.), оставив лишь FTP доступ для решения проблем?

Первая мысль - `sudo service nginx stop,` и веб сервер больше не работает, человек не запустит php скрипт.

Но безопасно ли это? Вдруг я завершу работу веб сервера в момент выполнения какого либо скрипта, и в последствии произойдет "не состыковка" данных (к примеру должно выполнится несколько запросов к БД, два выполнятся, третий нет).

*Я понимаю что вопрос обобщенный, и нет конкретики, но к сожалению я больше информации предоставить не могу, так как по сути ситуация имитирована.*

Comment: nginx не валенок же, он при остановке по идее должен прекратить приём запросов снаружи, дождаться выполнения текущих запросов, отдать ответы наружу и после этого завершить работу. Кроме того, он же не выполняет php скрипты. При остановке nginx сам php продолжает работать, так же как и база.

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, все нормальные веб-сервера и сервера приложений умеют дожидаться завершения работы текущих запросов перед остановкой. Если вы не делаете каких-то страшных вещей вроде отправки сигнала SIGKILL - то остановка любого демона (в линуксе) или службы (под виндами) обычно безопасна.

Во-вторых, используйте транзакции при работе с базой данных - и проблемы вида *"должно выполнится несколько запросов к БД, два выполнятся, третий нет"* обойдут вас стороной даже в случае пропадания питания или других способах аварийного завершения работы.

Ну и в-третьих, конкретно nginx не выполняет php-кода, эту работу за него делает php-fpm.

---

PS а для тех. работ лучше заранее заведите альтернативную версию конфига сервера, чтобы он на все запросы выдавал код [503](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/503) и страничку с описанием тех. работ.